Set symbol to discrete map with plotly scattermapbox - python
Is it possible to set a discrete symbol map for plotly scattermapbox. color and color_discrete_map can be used to assign a certain color but can the same approach be used to assign a specific symbol using a discrete map?
With below, I want to assign the symbol_dict to the unique values in species. Both px.scattermapbox or go.scattermapbox are viable.
The 2nd option doesn't return an error but it also doesn't show any of the points.
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.iris()

symbol_dict = {'versicolor': 'star', 'setosa': 'circle', 'virginica': 'diamond'}
smap = df["species"].map(symbol_dict)




fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    df,
    lat="sepal_width",
    lon="sepal_length",
    #symbol="species", # set symbol to species
    #symbol_map=symbol_dict, # set symbol to species
)




fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    lat=df['sepal_width'],
    lon=df['sepal_length'],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(symbol = smap)
    )
)

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style = "carto-positron")

fig.update_mapboxes(zoom = 5)

fig.show()


The symbols that can be used are the mapbox symbols, which are not Plotly symbols. For more information, see here.

Thanks. I'll try apply a discrete map with go.Scattermapbox?

The second method should work, but there are issues with symbols on mapbox, depending on the mapbox_style : it just doesn't work with "carto-positron". I tried with "light" style, star and circle symbols appear but the diamonds don't..

Thankyou. It works with that style. May need to be a second question or I can change this but I can't set both color and symbol using the same parameter. Only one works
